# Why does this not create a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Dim ComboBox2 As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Const cCount As Long = 2

Set ws = ActiveSheet(1)

With ws
    Set rng = .Range("H10")

    Set ComboBox2 = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                          Left:=rng.Left, _
                                          Top:=rng.Top, _
                                          Width:=rng.Width, _
                                          Height:=rng.Height)
With ComboBox2
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 100
        .Name = "myCombo"
End With
With Worksheets(5)
    Dim erg As Range: Set erg = .Range("D6", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count) _
        .End(xlUp)).Resize(, cCount)
    Worksheets(1).ComboBox2.ColumnCount = cCount
    Worksheets(1).ComboBox2.List = erg.Value
End With
End Sub
```

This code is in the workbook.
I am trying to create a combobox when someone opens this file and then have it to be populated from worsheet 5.
Its not happening, nothing is created and im also not getting any errors.

Comment: I Updated the original post.

Comment: Are you trying to open the workbook manually or by code? Also where have you placed this code? If the code is placed in a module and is opened manually then `Auto_Open` will work else it will not and hence it is advisable to use `Workbook_Open` in the thisworkbook Module. If the `Auto_Open` would have run, you would have got the error on `Set ws = ActiveSheet(1)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Workbook_Open event instead of Auto_Open event (it exist for backwards compatibility), the code should be placed in ThisWorkbook object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ComboBox2 As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Const cCount As Long = 2
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'Avoid using ActiveSheet, replace this with the worksheet name instead
    
    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("H10")
    
        Set ComboBox2 = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                              Left:=rng.Left, _
                                              Top:=rng.Top, _
                                              Width:=rng.Width, _
                                              Height:=rng.Height)
    End With
    
    With ComboBox2
            .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 100
            .Name = "myCombo"
    End With
    
    With Worksheets(5)
        Dim erg As Range
        Set erg = .Range("D6", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count) _
                    .End(xlUp)).Resize(, cCount)
    End With
    
    With Worksheets(1).ComboBox2
        .ColumnCount = cCount
        .List = erg.Value
    End With
End Sub
```